# How to get the closest row to the current date in my table?

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli, between

I would like to pull out the table from the database where the current day lands when the user visits the page.

Table Sample:

```
---+----------+-----------
ID |   from   |    to
---+----------+-----------
1  |2015-07-01|2015-07-14
---+----------+-----------
2  |2015-07-15|2015-07-31
---+----------+-----------
3  |2015-08-01|2015-08-20
```

OUTPUT:

if the date is `2015-07-10` the output should be `ID 1`

if the date is `2015-08-02` the output should be `ID 3`

Comment: ``where curdate() between `from` and `to` ``

Comment: What if the date is 2015-08-21?

Comment: @Strawberry if(!$row_sample){ echo do something;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, what you want to do is to select the row where today's date is between "from" and "to"?

If that's the case you should do something like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE CURDATE() >= `from`
    AND CURDATE() <= `to`
```

Or if you like:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table_name
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
```

Both queries will return one or many rows where today's date is in between "from" and "to".

Comment: This query will throw error for not escaping the reserve words.

Comment: I do suggest you change from -> from_date and to -> to_date so you do not get confused, as both from and to also part of build in mysql statements, but this is me.